# Python variable dictionary within a dictionary logic understanding issue

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I'm fairly new to concepts of Python, and practicing with dictionaries. I've a small bidding program where I'm trying to store dictionary within another dictionary as shown below which is not working how I expected:

```
# Initializing dictionaries
bidder_details = {}
bidders = {}

# Loop for storing bidders details
new_entry = "yes"
ID = 0
while new_entry.lower() == "yes":
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    amount = float(input("What's your bid?: "))
    ID += 1
    # Adding details to bidder_details dictionary
    bidder_details["bidder_name"] = name
    bidder_details["bid_amount"] = amount

    # Adding bidder_details with a key ID code into bidders
    bidders[ID] = bidder_details

    new_entry = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'\n").lower()
    if new_entry not in ("no", "yes"):
        print("\nIncorrect input! Taking no new bidders.")
        new_entry = "no"


print(f"\n{bidders}")
```

For multiple loop runs-
My expected output:

```
{1: {'bidder_name': 'Sam', 'bid_amount': 400.0}, 2: {'bidder_name': 'Ghost', 'bid_amount': 800.0}}
```

Resulted output:

```
{1: {'bidder_name': 'Ghost', 'bid_amount': 800.0}, 2: {'bidder_name': 'Ghost', 'bid_amount': 800.0}}
```

When I tried printing the bidders dictionary within the loop, result is same so I'm a bit confused why it's replacing my old data. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where do you take your input from? If it is the same, then input would be the same..

Comment: @Shuba inputs are collected from within the loop via console, however I was under the idea that with each iteration new values are replacing the old ones in bidder_details dictionary since the keys are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the same **bidder_details** dictionary for each **bidder**, and you're updating its values in each iteration of the loop. Since you're adding the same **bidder_details** dictionary to the **bidder** dictionary multiple times, only the last updated version of it is stored in the **bidder** dictionary, hence all the keys in the **bidder** dictionary refer to the same **bidder_details** dictionary.

To fix this, you should create a new **bidder_details** dictionary inside the while loop, before updating its values, so that each iteration of the loop uses a new **bidder_details** dictionary.
You can do something like this for the loop:

```py
while new_entry.lower() == "yes":
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    amount = float(input("What's your bid?: "))
    ID += 1
    # Creating a new bidder_details dictionary
    bidder_details = {}
    # Adding details to bidder_details dictionary
    bidder_details["bidder_name"] = name
    bidder_details["bid_amount"] = amount

    # Adding bidder_details with a key ID code into bidders
    bidders[ID] = bidder_details

    new_entry = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'\n").lower()
    if new_entry not in ("no", "yes"):
        print("\nIncorrect input! Taking no new bidders.")
        new_entry = "no"
```

Comment: Okay! Thanks I understand it now. I was thinking that since I'm assigning new values in every iteration it should have a fresh bidder_details dictionary.